# Is there a program similar to Spy++ for .NET applications?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, wndproc, spy++

I've looked around and I haven't found anything that fits my needs.
I wish for the program to be able to intercept the Win32 (?) messages that are being sent to my own application, which is written in Visual Basic.

As a side note, is "intercept the Win32 messages" the correct phrasing?

Either way, an elaboration won't hurt; I wish for the spy tool to intercept the same messages that I would programmatically intercept with WndProc, i.e: the SendMessages and PostMessages.

I wish to make it clear that I am **not** seeking a program that intercepts the .NET framework events.

Thanks.

Edits:
I **can** see my window and the handles of its child controls, but I do not receive any messages.
I am using Windows 7 64 bit.
My Spy++ version is 8.00.50727

Semi-solved; I have got a Spy++ alternative ([Window Detective](http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/about.html)) to work on my virtual machine, which I am most certainly happy with, and would definitely not mind settling for.

Although I am still wondering why all the "spy-like" programs I found did not work on my "main" PC... but I guess I needn't care.

Comment: It doesn't seem to want to work to "spy" on my application... I was under the impression that Spy++ was only for native programs.

Comment: I would have excepted Spy++ to work just as well for .net apps, since the messages are sent via the very same win32 apis. But I admit, I'm too lazy to test it myself now.

Comment: If you start your program after the spy++, you may have to refresh the window (F5) so that your program is in the window-list. Then there should be no problem to receieve the messages.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I just tested and it works as it should. No problem at all to receive messages from .Net-programs.

Comment: I launch my program before Spy++, do Spy > Log Messages (Ctrl + M), which then prompts me to select a window. I drag the finder tool onto my program, selecting the main form, not a child control of it. I see the window's information display in the window (title text, etc) and for extra measure I ensure that under "Additional Windows", everything is selected, apart from "All Windows in System". Under the message tab i ensure that everything is selected by be logged, and then I hit "OK".
I still don't see any messages. I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start Spy++ first and then launch your .Net program and use the Search/Find window to get the handle to the application you may get the "Cannot find window wich matches search criteria." and maybe thats why you think spy++ does not handle .Net applications.

Just press F5 to refresh the spy++'s list, and try again, now you should get the window and can start receieving messages from it.

Comment: Perhaps I should have specified further; I can see my window and the handles of its child controls, but I do not receive any messages.

Comment: Maybe it's something about you are running under 64 bit, are the program compiled for 64 or 32 bit?  Because it works for me (and im running under 32 bit)

Comment: Yeah I've figured it out a few minutes ago, I was just writing the final post/answer to wrap this failure of a question up in a nice, ugly, knot. You guys were pretty much right all long.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why Spy++ doesn't recognize any windows could be that you are running under a 64bit architecture and you thus tried to run the `spyxx_amd64.exe` application that is installed alongside the `spyxx.exe` (32bit?) version.

Even if you're running on 64bit, you should run the `spyxx.exe` program, since the former won't recognize any windows, at least for me.

The second part of the puzzle is making sure that Spy++ is refreshed using F5 (see @Stefan's post)